# Setting overflow to scroll on fixed div doesn't work

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

Overflow scroll won't work on fixed div, here is [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/mostafaellethy/pen/LNpyGp)

```
        #side-navbar {
          overflow: scroll;
          position: fixed;
          min-height: 100vh;
          width: 6rem;
          float: left;
          background-color: #000;
          -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
          -moz-box-shadow: 2px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
          box-shadow: 2px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
        }
```

`#side-navbar .logo img {
      margin: 0.5rem;
      width: 5rem;
      height: auto;
    }

    #side-navbar .menu-container {
      overflow:visible;
      min-height: calc(100vh - 24.6rem);
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -moz-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      -moz-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      align-items: center;
      width: 100%;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -moz-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    #side-navbar ul.social-menu {
      overflow: visible;
    }
</pre>`

Comment: Can you give more detail? What's the problem with it?

Comment: @Aurasphere When set overflow: scroll on my sidebar when items overflow the scroll won't work.
But the problem is solved by changing from min-height to height, thank you.

Comment: @Aurasphere I have tried but system notified me that I must wait 2 days to accept it :(

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Problem solved.
Using min-height keeps the menu render forever but when used height only scroll works perfectly.

Comment: Min height is not working on Safari browser. How to fixt it?

Answer (score 5):

Two things: first, try using `height` instead of `min-height`. Second, use `overflow-y:auto`, it works way better than `overflow:scroll`. Here is your code:

```css
 #side-navbar {
          overflow-y: auto;
          position: fixed;
          height: 100vh;
          width: 6rem;
          float: left;
          background-color: #000;
          -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
          -moz-box-shadow: 2px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
          box-shadow: 2px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
        }
```

```html
<div id="side-navbar">
<hr><hr><hr><hr><hr>ya scroll<hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr>ya scroll<hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr>ya scroll<hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr>ya scroll<hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr>ya scroll<hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr>ya scroll<hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr>ya scroll<hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr>ya scroll<hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr>ya scroll<hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr>ya scroll<hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr>ya scroll<hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr>ya scroll<hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr>ya scroll<hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr>ya scroll<hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr>ya scroll<hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr>ya scroll<hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr>ya scroll<hr><hr><hr><hr><hr>

</div>
```

It works in the snippet. Try it in your code. If you don't want to use overflow-y auto, just make sure to use `overflow-y:scroll` then.